# Where is the appropriate place to shout out I noticed SO just had over 10 million users?

Tags: discussion, users, statistics

I noticed SO just had over 10 million users. Not sure where to shout "hey guys, have you seen, it's 10 million now!".

[image: Stack Overflow: 10,000,199 total users]

Comment: Twitter, I imagine.

Comment: shortly John Skeet will be *top 0.000001%* ... well *top 0%*

Comment: another fun fact is, SO seems to be 1-based for array indexing, as there is no user 0, `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/0` returns page not found.

Comment: I wonder if there is somewhere we can see that Stack Overflow has 9M real users and 1M sock puppet accounts? `:=)`

Comment: @Indominus: in the olden days, when an account was deleted, it was really, really deleted. There *may have been* a user 0, but there is not one any more now, that's all we know. For example, there are no users with ids 6, 7, 12 or 14 *either*. See [this query for a list of no-longer-used-userids](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/975162/missing-user-ids). That said, MS SQL server auto-incrementing `IDENTITY` columns by default start at 1 unless specified otherwise. The SE data explorer copy of the database doesn't appear to include the `Users.id` `IDENTITY` settings, however.

Comment: @halfer: if only we could run a simple query to know what accounts are socks.. *sigh*.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I want to know who "John" Skeet is :p

Comment: @JonClements will tell you once *I* know it :p

Comment: We do start at 1 for user numbers but we also have user -1.

Comment: There are user numbers past -500, these are used for system users like The Chicken, Community, some Devs, and bots.

Comment: Not everybody has Twitter, @yivi, I am glad the OP posted that here, nice!

Comment: 7 downvotes so far... Red Freehand Circle may be?

Comment: @TemaniAfif If you ever manage to track him down, let him know that his name is really really close to the name of a famous SO user

Comment: @JonClements Dont google it, you (or even your ISP) may get blacklisted. :P

Comment: @MartijnPieters Your query has no sense of smell; that is why socks have to be found by hand.

Comment: @hat: yes, and so it is a good thing that us moderators have *excellent* senses of smell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the [new users page and sort by creation date](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=NewUsers&sort=creationdate), you will see the newest user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11014833/max.

Note that this is the 11,014,833<sup>th</sup> user entered into the database.

So, you were only off by about a million users as far as announcing the 10 millionth.

That said, (non staff) announcements are best left to personal blogs or social media.

Comment: Finally, somebody answering my question directly.

Comment: Newest user now, https://stackoverflow.com/users/11016275/ajeet-eppakayala

Comment: @U9-Forward - Actually, its https://stackoverflow.com/users/11019406/immo-hd

Comment: @TravisJ It is this user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11026225/estarshine

Comment: @U9-Forward - Are you sure? It looks like this user https://stackoverflow.com/users/11030834/kaml